# What's the meaning of "you got a point" and "take some money off of them"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [Friends S02E14](http://www.friendstranscripts.tk)

> ROSS: Monica, if you want, I can lend you some money.
>
> MONICA: No no no, if I couldn't pay you back right away then I'd feel
>   guilty and tense every time I saw you.
>
> ROSS: Oh OK. Well then why don't you, uhh, why don't you borrow it
>   from mom and dad? You feel guilty and tense around them already. You
>   might as well ***make some money off of them***.
>
> CHANDLER: Ya know, the man's ***got a point***.

I have two questions:

1. For the sentence *make some money off of them*, why did it add a preposition *of*? It's weird to me. I'm more familiar with *make some money off them*, because *off* already has a meaning of "from someone", which don't need an extra word *of* to emphasize again.
2. From the dictionary, I found that *get a point* means *score a point*, which is absolutely used in some competitions or quizzes. Is it a humorous way to say what the man said makes sense, or is it just a common expression to convey the agreement with someone?

Comment: *...I couldn't pay you back right away then I'd feel guilty and tense every time I **saw you.*** -that's also my concern. Saw you?

Comment: @MaulikV "saw" in "every time I saw you" is a use of the past-tense form to express the subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the complex preposition of *off of* is widely used, one may argue that it's redundant.

Here is the [Oxford Dictionaries' reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/off):

> Off of is often used in place of the preposition off in contexts such as she picked it up off of the floor (compared with she picked it up off the floor ). Although off of is recorded from the 16th century (it was used by Shakespeare) and is logically parallel to the standard out of, it is regarded as incorrect in standard modern English.

Now, about the *point*

> someone got a point - someone got an idea to think upon

Comment: Also pertinent, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English#Prepositions_and_adverbs): _In AmE, the compound "off of" may be used where BrE almost always uses "off", and "off of" is considered slang. Compare AmE "He jumped off of the box" and BrE "He jumped off the box"._ More about this on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619).

Answer (score 4):

> *get a point* means *score a point* – is it a humorous way to say what the man said makes sense?

Yes, it's a witty way to say "That makes sense." However, *point* in this case refers to [Definition #12 in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/point):

> **point** (*n.*) an essential element or thesis in an argument ⇒ *you've made your point, I take your point*

or [Definition #1 in Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/point):

> **point** (*n.*)  an idea or opinion among a number of others ⇒ *I disagree with you on a couple of points.*

So, perhaps a better way to paraphrase it would be:

> You know, the man **has a sound idea** – his idea is defensible.

Comment: +1 You might point out, for the benefit of those who are learning British English, that *has got* is not a present perfect but an idiom equivalent to bare *has*. It originated in AmE usage, where the past participle is *gotten* rather than BrE *got*.